# Authenticating addons and files

Tags: security, authentication, digital-signature

If you ever played the original startcraft and selected an official map made by Blizzard you would notice a little "Blizz" icon next to the map to let you know that it was official and not made by third-party.

I wish to implement a similar system in my application whereby addons and files can be authenticated to let the user know whether or not they came from me or somebody else.

I know very little about security and would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). The client application has a copy of the official author's public signing key, and verifies a signature applied to the addon/file made with the author's private key.

Answer (score 0):

Mac's answer is absolutely correct.  To be more specific, the process generally would go as follows:

Signing:

1. A hash (e.g. SHA-1) is created from the content.
2. The hash is then signed using the private key, resulting in a signature (e.g. using DSA or RSA algorithm).
3. The signature is included with the content.  If the content changes, the signature will become invalid.

Verification:

1. Client calculates a hash from the content.
2. The signature is decrypted with the known public key of the author (i.e. you).
3. If the hash inside the signature matches the calculated hash from #1 then it's OK.  Otherwise the content was modified / isn't really from the author (i.e. you).

Some considerations:

1. You need to use a key size large enough to deter brute forcing.
2. These algorithms require a source of random data - both when generating keys and when signing, for example.  If this is violated, then often the private key can be trivially revealed.
3. "Encrypting the hash with the public key" is a simplistic explanation.  For example, with RSA - the hash needs to be padded with other data.  On verification, the padding has to be checked as well.  Otherwise, the signatures may be able to be forged easily.  (See: OpenSSL debacle from a few years ago).

The standard advice is to use a proven, off-the-shelf cryptography library written by those with more experience.  You need to be able to feed the library the key pair, and data to be signed/verify and say "sign/verify this" with minimal code involved.  If you're worrying about the details of padding, or anything like that - you're probably doing it wrong.  See: System.Security.Cryptography namespace in Microsoft .NET (very easy to use), or Microsoft CryptoAPI if you're doing standard Windows C/C++ programming.  Other cross-platform libs exist too: pick something that works well on your platform.